# What is the base for the subspace defined by: $F= \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x − y + z = 0\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

What is a basis for the subspace defined by
$$F= \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x − y + z = 0\}?$$

Comment: What do you think the dimension of the subspace is?

Comment: I'm new and cannot comment. I just wanted to insist that there is no uniqueness of the base - as suggested in your question "What is THE base for the subspace" - if $(a,b)$ is a base of $\mathcal{F}$, then $(\alpha a,\beta b)$ is also a base, $(\alpha, \beta)\in{\mathbb{R}^{\star}}^2$.

Comment: And what is the condition for $(\alpha,\beta)$?

Comment: @pourjour $\mathbb R^\ast = \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$. The constraint is already specified by anderstood.

Comment: @pourjour: If $a=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$ and $b=\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$, then $(2a,-3b)=(\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
2\\
0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
3\\
0\\
-3
\end{pmatrix})$ will also be a base of $\mathcal{F}$. The condition can also be expressed as $\alpha\beta\neq 0$.

Comment: I got it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solving the equations for $x$ we have $x=y-z$ so the general element is 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
y-z\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix}
=y\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+z\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$$ so

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix} ,\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$$ is a basis.

Answer (score 2):

Just find two linearly independent vectors inside the space. Inspection gives

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 \\1 \\0\end{pmatrix},\, \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

immediately.

Answer (score 1):

$F = \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x-y+z=0\}$ can also be expressed as: $F= \{(x, y, y-x) \mid \forall (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\}$

So a basis for this is: $\{(1, 0, -1),(0,1,1)\}$